# Choose the biggest number in string in column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have some complicated task. I have some data in email column:

> borispil-admin@fff.com
>
> borispil2-admin@fff.com
>
> borispil5-admin@fff.com

I need to get biggest number. In example its **5**.

P.S. some time names can ends with number:

> kuhari24-admin@fff.com
>
> kuhari242-admin@fff.com
>
> kuhari243-admin@fff.com

Here the real name is kuhari24. And biggest number is **3**.
Here is my answer, but it very ugly. Have some one better idea?

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    (
        SELECT REPLACE(
            (
                SELECT MAX(email) 
                FROM account 
                WHERE email LIKE 'borispil%'
            )
        , '--admin@fff.com', '')
     )
, 'borispil', '') AS maxNumber
```

Comment: *"I'm working on MySQL"* Then please don't tag other RDBMS. I have removed [tag:sql-server].

Comment: "I'm trying RegEx" - please show us

Comment: How do you know if `abc24-admin` is a user or another `abc2` alternative?

Comment: I have abc2 name

Comment: Can you have more than 10 matches for an email?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff It could be

Answer (score -1):

You can easy use **REPLACE** and **+0** to find the Integer after a Name

SELECT
field-realname,
MAX(REPLACE(fiel-with-email,field-realname,'') + 0) as maximum_val
FROM your_table
group by fiels-realname;

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select REPLACE('kuhari243-admin@fff.com','kuhari24','') + 0;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| REPLACE('kuhari243-admin@fff.com','kuhari24','') + 0 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    3 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Why o you ownvote this answer ??

Comment: It does not do what I need. What if I have borispil-admin@fff.com

borispil2-admin@fff.com

borispil5-admin@fff.com such rows

Comment: and you also must have the real name like  kuhari24.. So you relace the realname ang group by it and you can give the max. i will add it in my answer .